# Dynamically generated NSTimers in same UITableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nstimer

I'm trying to implement a timer into a new application. One use case that is likely is to have more than one timer running at a time in the same view updating a UILabel or UIButton title text.

Does anyone have experience of doing this? what approach would you suggest.

The difficulty is when the timers fire off the same selector in short succession.

many thanks in advance

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .h file declare object:

```
NSTimer *myTimer1,myTimer2;
```

In .m file:

```
myTimer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(nextPhoto) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
myTimer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(nextPhoto) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

After the above invalidate the timers like this:

```
[myTimer1 invalidate];
[myTimer2 invalidate];
```

Try it like this.

Comment: thanks, I think I'll limit the timers running at one time to just 2 instances. I should hopefully avoid conflicts arrising from multiple hits of the same selector from different senders.

Answer (score 1):

If you do create repeating timers dynamically, you can run into problems with timer invalidation. I'd suggest you use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` methods instead.